# CASE WHEN is limiting the rows that are returned SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an Excel file from which I import data with a SQL Server command. The command runs fine but it seems to filter out data when I'm using a specific case statement. I can't find anything online about CASE filtering rows so I thought I'd ask here.

This code returns some 8000 rows

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN [Artikelnummer] = 'Extern' 
          THEN [Artikel SFC] 
          ELSE [Artikel Omschrijving] 
    END AS [Artikel Omschrijving 2],
    date.DifInDays([Actueel Geplande Leverdatum], [Geplande Leverdatum]) AS [Te Laat Dagen],
    date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5 AS [Gevraagde Dlt],
FROM 
    I_TN_Exp_PUR_tdpur041_004_2
WHERE 
    [bedrijf] = 103;
```

This code only returns ~70 rows.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN [Artikelnummer] = 'Extern' 
          THEN [Artikel SFC] 
          ELSE [Artikel Omschrijving] 
    END AS [Artikel Omschrijving 2],
    date.DifInDays([Actueel Geplande Leverdatum], [Geplande Leverdatum]) AS [Te Laat Dagen],
    date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5 AS [Gevraagde Dlt],
    CASE
       WHEN (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) >= [levertijd ITM]
             AND (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) >= [dlt bevestigd] 
          THEN 'OK'
       WHEN (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) >= [levertijd ITM]
             AND (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) < [dlt bevestigd] 
          THEN 'NOK'
       WHEN (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) < [levertijd ITM]
             AND (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) >= [dlt bevestigd] 
          THEN 'OK+'
       WHEN (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) < [levertijd ITM]
             AND (date.DifInDays([Geplande Leverdatum], [Orderdatum]) / 7 * 5) < [dlt bevestigd] 
          THEN 'OK/NOK'
       ELSE 'NOK'
    END AS [doorlooptijdcheck]
FROM
    I_TN_Exp_PUR_tdpur041_004_2
WHERE 
    [bedrijf] = 103;
```

The case statement is used to make a value that can be filtered on in the document ([doorlooptijdcheck]).

On certain values either a OK/NOK/OK+/NOK|OK is assigned.

Why is the when statement filtering out rows?

I've learned that the [Dlt bevestigd] is (blank) in the row after which it stops returning records. I've tried excluding it by using when [Dlt bevestigd] = '(blank)' Then 'no data' but that did not work. converting [Dlt bevestigd] to an int with Cast also didn't work. Seems like the (blank) value is exiting the  sql command.

Comment: What is an example of a row that is getting filtered out that you would expect to be included?

Comment: Good tip, i have found out that it just does the first 69 rows and then it returns 3 rows with (blank) for every value and after that no more. The sequence in the first 69 rows is exactly the same with the two queries.

Comment: Do your column names really have line breaks in them? I suspect not, as then you have a column `[levertijd ITM]` and `[levertijd {new line}ITM]`, which seems rather silly (I removed them in my edit, assuming that you don't really). Also, that first statement isn't actually valid, there's a trailing comma (`,`) after `[Gevraagde Dlt]`. Is that actually the full SQL?

Comment: There is no new lines, that is just the text editor on stackoverflow. The comma after  [Gevraagde Dlt] is for the case statement that comes next. If i remove that comma i get an error.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get it to fit on one line?

Comment: can you post your table with some sample data?

Comment: Are you checking the resultset from SSMS or from Excel? Is the data coming from SQLServer into Excel, or the other way?

Comment: If you import the data using the first query (into a staging table), then run the second query on the imported data (not from the spreadsheet), what happens?

Comment: Trying to upload a excell document with a couple example rows. I don't want to get sued though so have to be carefull with what i post online.

Comment: https://docdro.id/xC7Rn4d

Comment: I've learned that the [Dlt bevestigd] is (blank) in the row after which it stops returning records. I've tried excluding it by using when [Dlt bevestigd] = '(blank)' Then 'no data' but that did not work. converting [Dlt bevestigd] to an int with Cast also didn't work. Seems like the (blank) value is exiting the  sql command.